# Vaio Windows 8 Upgrade screen resolution

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-FE41E and have just upgraded it to Windows 8. However, the screen resolution is fixed at 1024 x 768 (no other options) and the only monitor that the computer can detect is the basic windows one. Does anyone have any suggestions as at the moment I have huge fonts on the scree.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install the video drivers again (or updates from sony website)? 
You should try Windows 7 drivers;
You could try this: 
http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VGN-FE41E/updates

Here you find solutions for Windows 8 http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/topics/solutions/36760

Comment: thanks for pointing me to Sony's website. I have the latest Vaio update software and it's not detecting any updates. Nobody else seems to have this problem, so I guess I'll have to wait for more people to install Windows 8 or for Sony to release a new driver.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the latest **NVIDIA GeForce Go 7400**  driver:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_179.48_beta.html
http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_179.48_beta.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is your *monitor* driver, not you video adapter driver. Never used W8, but here's what I'd do on W7:

1. Open the display resolution control panel applet (desk.cpl).
2. Look at the "Display" drop down. It should say "mobile display" or something Sony-specific. If it says "generic display", you're using a fallback monitor driver that doesn't do resolution.
3. If the above is true, find the Sony monitor driver for W8, download and install the Sony monitor driver. Otherwise, post a comment telling me that I'm full of it!

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no problema with the monitor or drivers required to function, its ONLY the GeForce Go 7400/7600 driver not correctly instaled, thats why u dont have the 1280*800 resolution. Use the modified drivers from Laptop2go website with their modedd INF configuration file. I play EVE Online and LoL on a FE41S (GF7600) and no problems, having currently instaled the 307.32 in Win7. Dont use or install the Vaio Update or Vaio Care, models r too old and only do partial updates, folow the updates listed on suport site and update some from others sources, cheers.